# Console Input in Java (Integer)

Tags: java

I need to take integer input from Console.

```
import java.io.IOException;
class tst{
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws IOException
    {
        int t=(int)System.in.read();
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be 2 but the actual output is 50
How to resolve?

Comment: what is the input you provided? why don't you use the Scanner class?

Comment: My input was 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `System.in.read()` reads the next `char`, and in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), char `2` corresponds to the decimal number `50`.

Use the class [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead, which function `int nextInt()` does exactly what you need:

```
int t = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
System.out.println(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer said, you are getting the ASCII value using `System.in.read`. If you still want to use that method, you can covert it to `int` with following line:

```
int t = Character.getNumericValue(System.in.read());
```